# Four columns in a row

Tags: css

I have four small images in a row like a menu on the start page which goes to sub pages. The images a placed like this:

*image space image space image space image*

But I don't get an equl space before the last image! Is there a way to solve this? All images are placed in a container that has a width of 100%.

I use the CSS like this:

```
.one-fourth {
width: 24%;
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;

}

.last {
margin-right: 0%;
float: right;
}
```

The fourth and last image also has the class `.last`

Comment: Is there a reason for using float: right; for the .last? Try removing the float:right;

Comment: Please share your HTML too.

Comment: @gopalraju If I use left then I get some extra white space to the right

Comment: Add the fiddle, or a markup here. Also add the pseudoelements `:before` and `:after` on the container, that will have `content: " "; display: table;`, and the after will clear the floats `clear: both;`. Then just float the elements to the left, and set the margin of every fourth to zero (or to the last).

Comment: I think you should use `ul` and `li`, set `ul` `width: 100%` and `li` same like your `.one-fourth` and instead of `.last` use `li:last-child`. This solution is more problem-proof.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper:before,
.wrapper:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}
.one-fourth {
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.333333%;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1.333333%;
}
.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one-fourth">asasdasds</div>
  <div class="one-fourth">rtzrtzrtzr</div>
  <div class="one-fourth">uizuizui</div>
  <div class="one-fourth last">xcvxcvxcvxcv</div>
  <div class="one-fourth">dsfsdfsfsfsdf</div>
  <div class="one-fourth">xcvxcvxvc</div>
  <div class="one-fourth">werwrewerwe</div>
  <div class="one-fourth last">werwerwer</div>
  <div class="one-fourth">werwerwe</div>
  <div class="one-fourth">werwrwerwe</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to use flexbox.  Just have the parent set to `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.  All children will be set into a row (flexbox's default setting). Just set each image's width to a bit less than 25%.  Otherwise there will be no space between each one.  If you really want exactly 1% between each one then set the width using calc to `width: calc(97% / 4)`.

I've used a simple css reset to make the effect more clear.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.one-fourth {
  width: calc(97% / 4);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/city" alt="Lorem Ipsum" class="one-fourth"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/sports" alt="Lorem Ipsum" class="one-fourth"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/people" alt="Lorem Ipsum" class="one-fourth"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/nature" alt="Lorem Ipsum" class="one-fourth"/>
</section>
```

For more on flexbox here's a [snippet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) from css-tricks, and the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

Without an example it's hard. But works this for you?

```
.one-fourth {
width: 24%;
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one-fourth:last-child {
margin-right:0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy cross-browser way to do that using `text-align: justify`:

On the container and all children:

```
.container {
  text-align: justify;
}

.container > * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Now create in the end of your container one more element, e.g. div with class last-text-line:

```
.last-text-line {
  width: 100%;
}
```

That will force your images to stretch to the whole width of the container with automatically generated margins. You won't even need to separate them by classes.

[Fiddle](https://jsbin.com/yizobazipe/edit?html,css,output)

How it works: justify tries to stretch the text to the width given. But the last row is always not stretched. That is fixed by our last element with 100% width - it is becoming the last row and the rows above are stretched to the given width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw your code a fiddle and when I set the with to 25%, I get the last image on the next row?!

Comment: This is happening due to the spaces between image elements. Remove all the spaces e.g. like [this](https://jsbin.com/yizobazipe/edit?html,css,output). This is a seldom case when spaces in HTML play the role

Comment: But I want some space between the images, but not after the last.

Comment: @AndréR., no, it is because of space symbol and `display: inline-block` elements. It is treated as a text that is why all spaces are transformed into one as it was a text -> spaces are important and must be removed. You might fix it with negative margin but the value is depending on the font size and font family you are using + could be different in different browsers -> so the easiest solution is just to kill the spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

your `last` class floats *right* ... and you have not set the width explicitly for class `last` ... [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3mtLcoqg/) worked for me

```
.one-fourth {
width: 24%;
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;
}

.last {
width: 25%;
float: left;
margin-right: 0%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but then the last image will be 1% wider than the other!?

Comment: i set it to 25% to have 100% as a whole ... but the effect of positioning the elements in rows also works if you set width:24% for class last.